# How to get different texts from the HTML DOM through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

In the following example:

```
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>

    <td>
    </td>

    <td>
    </td>

    <td>
    </td>

    <td>
        text1
        <br>
        <img>
        <br>
        text2
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I try to get the text in the 5th td like so:

```
something = elem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text
```

I get both texts in the same variable. I can split them but I was wondering if I can somehow get them in individual variables so I don't bother with a split. However when I try something like this:

```
something = elem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]/text()[1]')
```

I get the following error message:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: 
The result of the xpath expression "./td[5]/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. 
It should be an element.
```

Can I get around this error somehow?

Comment: Because Selenium requires the return result of `find_element` must be  Element Node,  your `/td[5]/text()[1]` will return a Text Node, this why you get the error. For What's Element/ Text Node, you can read HTML DOM document, for node in DOM Tree, it has 3 types, Element and Text is two types of the 3 types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below code to get two separate text nodes:

```
something = elem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]')
text1 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', something).strip()
text2 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', something).strip()
```

Comment: Thanks you solution worked wonderfully. If you have time and don't mind I'd love it if you walk me through the code. It would help immensely. Particularly what does the script part and the strip part do.

Comment: Each variable is a result of JavaScript code. `arguments[0]` is a placeholder for `something` element. So the first code means *return the text value of the first child node of td*, second is the same for last child node of td. Note that *child nodes of td* are: 1. "text1", 2. br, 3. "" 4. img, 5.br, 6. "", 7. "text2". `strip()` just allows you to get rid of leading and trailing new-line characters and spaces. Also `firstChild`/`lastChild` can be replaced with explicit index e.g. `childNodes[0]`, `childNodes[6]`

Comment: My wholehearted thanks. How would it have been written if it was the second and fourth child instead of the first and last for which there are specific functions?

Comment: I've updated my previous comment. You can use `arguments[0].childNodes[N]` to get N-th node

Answer (score 1):

In your initial code trial when you used :

```
something = elem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text
```

You got both the elements **text1** and **text2** as both the text were part of `<td[5]>`

In your next code trial when you used :

```
something = elem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]/text()[1]')
```

Raised **`InvalidSelectorException`** because, though **./td[5]/text()** is a valid `xpath` expression but currently is not supported by *Selenium*. Hence the error is raised.

To extract the texts **text1** and **text2** from the *HTML* you have provided you can use the [**`str.splitlines`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method as follows :

```
text1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr//following-sibling::td[5]").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[1]
text2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr//following-sibling::td[5]").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer its more clear than the other answer to me but as far as I understand it, it will only work with properly formatted html. If lets say the texts were at the same line as the tags, what would happen than? Would it break?

Comment: I am afraid. I thought you tagged `Python` but not `JavaScript` my solution is more **Pythonic** indeed. Perhaps you wanted to look at  [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

Comment: @cybera Yes, you are right when you say `it will only work with properly formatted html`. Factually, the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) is always in a formated state. It all boils down how the end user interprets it. Incase `texts were at the same line as the tags` we would have fine tuned our approach but the algorithm would have been same being **Pythonic**.